# Separating a quiz questions into different groups

Tags: java, android

I've searched a lot for this question but can't seem to actually find an answer. My quiz app works well, but I realized that 50 questions all at once were too many.

Right now, my app works by people clicking a button that says "Begin" and they enter the quiz. After the quiz, all of the questions that they got wrong are shown with the correct answer. However, what I'd like to do is group these into questions of 10. So, select "Question Set 1" Button, "Question Set 2" Button, etc. Then, I'd still like to show the correct answer to the questions contained in this question set.

I'm not actually sure how to separate the questions and have my logic still work. Below I've included by database helper class. I've exempted most of the questions to shorten it. Thank you so much!

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "realEstateQuiz";
    // tasks table name
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    // tasks Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "questionId";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; // correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTA = "opta"; // option a
    private static final String KEY_OPTB = "optb"; // option b
    private static final String KEY_OPTC = "optc"; // option c
    private static final String KEY_OPTD = "optd"; // option d

    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase = db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( " + KEY_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTA
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTB + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC + " TEXT," + KEY_OPTD + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        addQuestions(db);
        // db.close();
    }

    private void addQuestions(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Question q1 = new Question(
                "When a real estate professional exaggerates " + "about a parcel of property, they are likely:",
                "Misrepresenting the property", "Guilty of fraud", "Puffing", "All of the above", "Puffing");
        this.addQuestion(q1, db);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    // Adding new question
    public void addQuestion(Question quest, SQLiteDatabase db) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQuestion());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getAnswer());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOpta());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOptb());
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOptc());
        values.put(KEY_OPTD, quest.getOptd());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
    }

    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question quest = new Question();
                quest.setQuestionId(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQuestion(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setAnswer(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOpta(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOptb(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setOptc(cursor.getString(5));
                quest.setOptd(cursor.getString(6));
                quesList.add(quest);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return quest list
        cursor.close();
        dbase.close();
        return quesList;
    }

    public int rowcount() {
        int row = 0;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        row = cursor.getCount();

        cursor.close();
        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simply add an integer column (i.e.: `QuestionSet`) and get only the questions `... WHERE QuestionSet = ?`, passing the question set it. Obviously, 10 questions will have a value of 1, other 10 will have a value of 2, ... and so on. Or start from 0 (even better - but it's only personal taste, not necessarily functional)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your Question objects  and corresponding table should contain an additional field which indicates which Question Set they belong to. Your DbHelper class should then beable to query Questions by set. Or alternatively you could sort all Questions by their set in the java code, but I would prefer to leave that to the db.

However, If you wish to divide all the questions into sets of 10 you could try something like the following:

```
List<Set<Question>> questionSets = new ArrayList<Set<Question>>();
Set<Question> questionSet = new HashSet<Question>();
questionSets.add(questionSet);

int counter = 0;
for(Question question : dbHelper.getAllQuestions()){
  if(++counter > 10){
     counter = 0;
     questionSet = new HashSet<Question>();
     questionSets.add(questionSet);            
  }

  questionSet.add(question);
}
```

This will collect ten questions into a Set and the add them to the list of Question Sets. You could then access each question set from that list.